# Woocommerce order categories by category order as per admin section

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In the woocommerce categories screen you can drag and drop the categories to change their order.

In the "front end" I want to list the categories in this same order (same custom order as per the drag and drop of Product Categories screen in wp-admin).

```
$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
  'orderby'      => 'term_order',
  'order'        => 'asc',
  'show_count'   => 0,
  'pad_counts'   => 0,
  'hierarchical' => 1,
  'title_li'     => '',
  'hide_empty'   => 0,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I have tried several different orderby variations but can't get the exact same order as per the admin screens.  The ordering data seems to be stored in the ??__woocommerce_termmeta table with 'meta_key' of 'order'.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that WooCommerce is already changing the query in the case of `product_cat` taxonomy. For example:

```
$args = array(
    'parent'        => 0,
    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat'
);

$categories = get_categories( $args );
```

Executed query will look like this:

> SELECT t.*, tt.*, tm.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
>   AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_termmeta AS
>   tm ON (t.term_id = tm.woocommerce_term_id AND tm.meta_key = 'order')
>   WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('product_cat') AND tt.parent = '0' ORDER BY
>   tm.meta_value+0 ASC, t.name ASC

And categories are taken in the same order as in the admin section.

Comment: Thanks, never worked that out as the code always had an orderby in it. Cheers!